# Elastic Search: Can I aggregate with more than one date field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some data from running scripts in my elasticsearch:

```
{
"start":"2015-06-15T10:48:01.451Z",
"resolved":true,
"cmd":"blabla",
"lastUpdate":"2015-06-18T11:28:36.866Z",
"end":"2015-06-17T11:28:35.768Z"
}
```

My goal is to see for the last x days whether scripts are running. Running scripts have a start time in field "start" and a end time in field "end". In this case I expect a view like:

```
{ "date":"2015-06-14", "doc_count":"0",
  "date":"2015-06-15", "doc_count":"1",
  "date":"2015-06-16", "doc_count":"1",
  "date":"2015-06-17", "doc_count":"1",
  "date":"2015-06-18", "doc_count":"0" 
}
```

Is this possible to implement with aggregations or something else? How can I build this?

Thanks for any suggestions!

I already experimented with aggregations but they didn't met my needs. I can always refer one date field and not consider days between start and end.

```
"aggs" : {
    "range" : {
        "date_range" : {
            "field" : "start",
            "format" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
            "ranges" : [
                {"to": "now", "from": "now/d"},
                {"to": "now/d", "from": "now-1d/d"},
                {"to": "now-1d/d", "from": "now-2d/d"},
                {"to": "now-2d/d", "from": "now-3d/d"},
                {"to": "now-3d/d", "from": "now-4d/d"},
                {"to": "now-4d/d", "from": "now-5d/d"},
                {"to": "now-5d/d", "from": "now-6d/d"}
            ]
        }
    },
```

Comment: I think a possible resolution is to use scripted fields in elastic. But at the moment I have trouble with double square brackets in the return of the query. I'm not sure why and what is the next step. I have an other ticket because the brackets [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022483/elasticsearch-script-field-answer)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue I use a script to calculate the intresting days. 
Here are my query with the aggregation:

```
"query" : {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "should" : [ 
                    { "range" : { "lastUpdate" : {"gt" : "now-10d/d"} } },
                    { "range" : { "start"      : {"gt" : "now-10d/d"} } },
                    { "range" : { "end"       : {"gt" : "now-10d/d"} } }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "dates" : {
        "terms" : {
            "script_file" : "multidate"
        }
    }
}
```

It's related to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script).

I think the script isn't done but good as example:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory
import groovy.json.*

def term = []
use(TimeCategory) {

def lastUpdate = doc['lastUpdate'].date.toDate()
def start      = doc['start'].date.toDate()
def end        = doc['end'].date.toDate()

// Start befor end
  if(start<end) {
    // lastUpdate only use if after end
    if(end<lastUpdate&&(lastUpdate-end).days>0) {
      term.push(lastUpdate)
    }
    // days between start and end
    // same day?
    if(start.format("dd.MM.yyyy")==end.format("dd.MM.yyyy")) {
      // same day!
      term.push(start)
    } else {
      // another day
      diff = end-start
      for(i=0;i<=diff.days;i++) {
        term.push(start+i.days)
      }
      if((start+diff.days).format("dd.MM.yyyy")!=end.format("dd.MM.yyyy")) {
        term.push(end)
      }
    }
  }
}

text = []
for(i in term) {
  text.add(i.format("dd.MM.yyyy"))
}

text
```

Thats it! If I run the query i get:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "dates" : {
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "18.06.2015",
        "doc_count" : 2
      }, {
        "key" : "19.06.2015",
        "doc_count" : 2
      }, {
        "key" : "25.06.2015",
        "doc_count" : 2
      }, {
        "key" : "17.06.2015",
        "doc_count" : 1
      }, {
        "key" : "22.06.2015",
        "doc_count" : 1
      }, {
        "key" : "23.06.2015",
        "doc_count" : 1
      }, {
        "key" : "30.06.2015",
        "doc_count" : 1
      } ]
    }
  }
```